# Need to disable Ui when popup is open

Tags: c#, popup, windows-store-apps

In my Windows Store app (c#) i have Popup:

```
<Popup x:Name="LoginPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="400" Height="300" IsOpen="{Binding Path=LoginPopupIsOpen}">
            <Popup.ChildTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <PopupThemeTransition />
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Popup.ChildTransitions>
</Popup>
```

And when Popup IsOpen I need handle events only on Popup and freeze all another UI (including AppBar). 
 It is possible without creating full screen popup with little work area?

Comment: The simple answer is, No. I think Callisto or Caliburn has a CustomDialog type of interaction that will do it for you (and allow you to set the Content arbitrarily), but other than that I don't think there is a simple property you can set to do this for you. You could add a cover Canvas or something to a custom page class, then have a custom Popup trigger that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the xaml.cs file by using two properties.
In the event handler for the popup you are creating you can include the following two lines

```
this.IsEnabled = false;
this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
```

in the event handler where you want to close the popup, you can revert the properties back to their original values.

```
this.IsEnabled = true;
this.ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar problem and used this to handle that.

```
        private void AlertMessage_Opened(object sender, object e)
    {
        UIBlock.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void AlertMessage_Closed(object sender, object e)
    {
        UIBlock.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

My popup name was AlertMessage and I attack opened and closed events with it and place a border in xaml which covers whole screen, and handle is visibility through these events.

```
    <Border Name="UIBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="#AAFFFFFF" Visibility="Collapsed">
    </Border>
```

And remember to place this border before popup

Answer (score 0):

I have made small popup using below code.Please try this.

```
<Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.7"  Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="gdalert" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=gdfullpage}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=gdfullpage}">
            <Popup x:Name="settingpopup"  Width="350" Grid.Row="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Border x:Name="settingbdrmain"  Grid.Row="1"  BorderThickness="0"  Width="350"  CornerRadius="15" >
                    <Grid x:Name="gdsubshape" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dddf" FontSize="20" Text="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" ></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="txtsettingalert"  Text="" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center" Width="300" FontFamily="Arial"   TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="Black" Grid.Row="1" ></TextBlock>
                        <Border x:Name="settingbdr" Width="350" Grid.Row="2" Height="1" Background="Red" BorderBrush="Black" >
                        </Border>
                        <Grid x:Name="btnpanel" Grid.Row="3" Height="60">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">/ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button x:Name="settingok"   Grid.Column="0"  Height="50"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="20"  Width="170" Content="OK" FontSize="24" Foreground="Green" ></Button>
                            <Border  x:Name="settingsubbdr"  Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Green" Height="Auto" Width="1" ></Border>
                            <Button x:Name="sl" Grid.Column="2"  Height="50"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinHeight="20"  Width="170" Content="Cancel" FontSize="24" Foreground="Green" ></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
```

To Open Use :- popname.IsOpen = true; gdalert.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

To Close popname.IsOpen = false; gdalert.Visibility = Visibility.Collapse;